# Why are our traffic stats so low?

Tags: support, site-evaluation

Right now the block on the right side of Main lists the usual stuff: ~6,5k questions, around 20k answers, 100% answered and ~22k users. But one stat seems to be quite far off:

We currently have 55 visitors/day according to the "Site Stats".

The 5k site analytics tool shows that this has been the case since 12.04.2018, where we first dropped from ~6,5k to ~100 and further down to 14 on Sunday.

I think since I've started being active on the site the stat was somewhere like 6 to 9k each day, except for the slower weekends. 55 visitors/day seems to be extremely far off and doesn't really seem to align with the amount of traffic we've seen in the last days. For example [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35084/how-to-prevent-seeming-like-a-marty-stu-ish-villain-is-cheating) was asked yesterday and has more than 3,5k views. I can't imagine that having an HNQ and our regulars would only give us a total of ~55 visitors/day. [Is it ok to reference names of real world people?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35127/is-it-ok-to-reference-names-of-real-world-people) is another HNQ that has been asked today.

For example the screenshot in the Meta discussion [Why is the Writers site still called Beta?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1309/23159) from mid-July 2017 shows ~6,5k visitors/day.

Does anyone know why the "Site Stats" are so far off? Or why they are so different to the values I remember seeing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [network-wide problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309087/162102) -- something's broken in the path from Google Analytics to the reports we get in that summary box (for beta sites), in the [site analytics that high-rep users can see](https://writing.stackexchange.com/site-analytics), on Area 51, and in the moderator tools.

The problem started in early April.  Because Area 51 (and that summary box) shows a rolling average, it's been steadily declining since then.  We've now reached the "no, you've *got* to be kidding" stage with that stat.

We have way more visitors than what's currently showing.  Everybody does.  (For our site, I saw stats in the 9k range in March.)